# If $3n^3-5n^2-4n-2$ can be divided by $n-2$ . Find all possible integer values for $n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $3n^3-5n^2-4n-2$ can be divided by $n-2$ , Find all possible integer values for $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remainder theorem:

$P(n)=3n^3-5n^2-4n-2$ is divided by $(n-2)$,

the remainder is $P(2).$

$P(2)=$

$2(2^3)-5(2^2) -4(2) -2=-6.$

$P(n)$ is divisible by $(n-2)$ if $(n-2)|(-6).$

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$3n^3-5n^2-4n-2=$$

$$3n^3-6n^2+n^2-2n-2n+4-6=$$

$$(n-2)(3n^2+n-2)-6$$

it is divisible if $n-2$ divise $6$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3n^3-5n^2-4n-2}{n-2}=3n^2+n-2-\frac6{n-2}$$
This is an integer iff $n-2\mid 6$.